# Concrete example of Earnshaw's Theorem

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm struggling to understand [Earnshaw's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem). I've tried reading the original paper, and the wikipedia article. I know enough math to be able to understand the mathematics of the theorem, but I cannot see the connection to physical reality clearly enough to understand completely. The theorem is quite general. It would be very helpful to see an example, where an attempt is made of constructing something that intuitively should work (levitation), and demonstrating how the theorem applies; why the example won't work.

Comment: Not sure if this is quite what you're asking for, but there's a nice conceptual discussion of what it means [here](http://skullsinthestars.com/2009/04/13/levitation-and-diamagnetism-or-leave-earnshaw-alone/).